# Given the OSM data for a state, find its area

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis

Apologies if this is a silly question, I'm very new to PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

I have downloaded an .osm file for the entire state of Baden-Württemberg from here - https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/baden-wuerttemberg.html

I have to answer the following questions, by writing queries for the same -

1. What is the area (expressed in m^2) of Baden-Württemberg?
2. What is by area the smallest city of Baden-Württemberg?

I have imported the osm file into a PostgreSQL using the **osm2pgsql** tool.

There seem to be multiple tables that are being created, core and generated by osm2pgsql. In addition to the core tables - ***planet_osm_nodes***, ***planet_osm_ways*** and ***planet_osm_rels*** there are other tables as well, and I'm not quite sure how to use them to complete my tasks.

It would be really helpful if anybody could provide some insight into how I can go about writing the PostGIS query for the same.

Comment: crossposts: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314541/given-the-osm-data-for-a-state-find-its-area-by-writing-a-postgis-query and https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/68291/given-the-osm-data-for-a-state-find-its-area-by-writing-a-postgis-query

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should give you the cities and their area in square meters in order

```
SELECT *, ST_Area(way) 
FROM planet_osm_polygon
WHERE boundary='administrative'
AND admin_level=7
ORDER BY ST_Area(way)
```

Same thing should work with the border of Baden-Württemberg only that you would need `admin_level=4`

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Grenze